# Deploy gradle to directory

Tags: java, gradle, deployment

This may have been asked to death, but I can't find an answer. I have a pretty simple java project (not web), its built with ant with sources located in ./src and dependencies in ./lib. Looking to modernize it to either maven or gradle. Since I've had good results with gradle and android, decided to go with gradle. That means I'll be dropping ./lib for dependency management.

However, I cannot figure out how to use grade to deploy the project. I would like to deploy manually for now. So I would need to have jar build from the sources and having all dependencies copied into lib (or whatever) directory where jar is.

So far... I'm getting nowhere quickly.

Comment: Take a look at the gradle application plugin.

Comment: wow ok that was really simple. Can you make this an answer so it can be accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gradle Application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) is perfectly suited for this use-case.

the task `distZip` will create a deployable zip file complete with dependencies.